# Java Food Diary

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

The goal of this project is to create a Food Diary. This diary should contain breakfast, lunch, dinner and Snacks that you consume during the day. The user should be able to enter their food items and save it as a csv file. The user should be able to keep appending to the file.

This is what I have so far but I'm not sure where to close my scanner:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("test.csv"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Date");
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append("FoodTime");
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append("FoodItem");
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append("Calories");
        sb.append('\n');


        int exit;
        do {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Date : ");
            String Date = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Meal Time: ");
            String FoodTime = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Food Item : ");
            String FoodItem = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Calories : ");
            String Calories = sc.next();
            sb.append(Date);
            sb.append(',');
            sb.append(FoodTime);
            sb.append(',');
            sb.append(FoodItem);
            sb.append(',');
            sb.append(Calories);
            sb.append('\n');
            pw.write(sb.toString());
            System.out.println("Please enter 0 to exit, 1 to continue : ");
            exit = sc.nextInt();
        } while (exit != 0);


        System.out.println("done!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Please follow Java naming conventions : attributes, variables, parameters, method have to start in lowerCase

Comment: You close your Scanner at the end of your main method, when you're done using it. And in fact you should create the Scanner **before** the do-while loop. A program should create only **one** Scanner based on System.in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new scanner on every interaction inside your do while.
Try to create a new scanner before the loop and close it after.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
        System.out.println("Date : ");
        String Date = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Meal Time: ");
        String FoodTime = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Food Item : ");
        String FoodItem = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Calories : ");
        String Calories = sc.next();
        sb.append(Date);
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append(FoodTime);
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append(FoodItem);
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append(Calories);
        sb.append('\n');
        pw.write(sb.toString());
        System.out.println("Please enter 0 to exit, 1 to continue : ");
        exit = sc.nextInt();
    } while (exit != 0);
sc.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create the Scanner Object Before the do loop because at every iteration a new object is being created and you should close the Scanner Object after the end of do loop.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure where to close my scanner:

To answer your question, you need to close it right before the last line:

```
pw.close();
sc.close();
System.out.println("done!");
```

You need to also declare the Scanner outside of the do loop:

```
int exit;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
```